# Is there a way to calculate difference initial water content, from curve number method?

Tags: hydrology, water, soil, agriculture, runoff

I want to calculate difference between initial water content of a soil given that its saturation water content can be found from its type. Is there a way to find initial water content of that soil from methods like curve number method?